# oscillation in overcurrent shutdown circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, circuit-protection

I've tried to design an overcurrent shutdown circuit, what turned out to be more complicated than I thought. 
The specifications:

- PSU from 5V to 40V
- Shut down at currents >= 1A
- At most a Watt or so of dissipated power after shut down
- Very low voltage drop in "on" state (say at most 0.5V)
- No use of electro-mechanical relays
- No use of surge current thermistors (I dislike them)

So, my proposed      solution was to test the voltage drop in a resistance of 0.01Ohm, and to switch a low on resistance hexfet on or off. I ended up with the following circuit:
[image: Overcurrent shutdown Circuit]

When running a simulation with LTspice, with a voltage ramping from 0 to 20V it turned out that the circuit works almost as desired (to shut down when the current exceeds 1A), but in place of shutting down, it sends very sharp peaks from 0 to 1A (see figure below), at a frequency depending on the value of the capacitance of the capacitor (without a capacitor, the frequency is very high, with a 1mF capacitor, the frequency is of 0.1Hz or so). Note that the location of the capacitor is not mandatory: it can be put in many other places, with a similar effect. I've struggled to prevent these oscillations, without success. 
It seems that the circuit want to shut down, but the FET struggles to maintain its gate high.

My questions are:

1. What is the exact cause of these (relaxation?) oscillations ?
2. How to make this circuit work ?

[image: simulation]

Comment: As soon as your over-current circuit activates - it obviously shuts the supply to your load off - leading to no current flowing - so no more over-current condition - so of course it turns back on again - rinse and repeat. What you seem to be expecting is *fold-back* current limiting - which requires some hysteresis/positive-feedback which your circuit is lacking.

Comment: brhans, I think you have missed the "thyristor like" unit in the circuit: once it is fired, it should remain on the "on" state.

Comment: Why is the comparator powered through a 100k resistor?! (And why is your LTspice font so tiny?)

Comment: Sorry for the font (actually, zooming the screen works well). The 100k resistor is not the problem (same effect with 1k resistor). Actually, after a lot of struggling, I've found the solution: to add a feedback voltage divider to the sense + terminal of the comparator ending at the other side of the FET. I'm planning to delete this question (sorry for all who have waste their time), so if someone think this question has some interest for the community, let me know.

Comment: @MikeTeX -- self-answer it instead.  Having a record of your silly mistake might save someone some real head-scratching at their bench some day!

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to the cause of the oscillation is that the "thyristor like" unit does not remains in the on state after it has been fired (the same is true if it is replaced by a true thyristor). It may be interesting to understand why. Regarding a solution, I finally found that adding a feedback voltage divider to the sense + terminal does the trick; when this is done, the thyristor machinery become unnecessary, and this gives the following simpler circuit, which works well in spice simulations:

[image]
The principle is simply that the voltage comparator is maintained in the high state by the voltage divider whenever the FET is "off", while the sensed voltage is almost the same as without the feedback voltage divider whenever the FET is "on".